# Count Down timer does not work correctly in android

Tags: android, timer, count

I implemented a count down timer (2 min) 1:59 --> 00:00 
but after a while it is not working properly and gets crazy!
Like this : 01:46 - 01:45 - 01:46 - 01:43 - 01:42 ...
What is going wrong? Edit : timer is in Fragment
Thanks in advance.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ApplicationLauncher.mainComponent().inject(this);
    setActionBarHidden(true);
    setDrawerLocked(true);
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(120000, 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimerTv.setText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimerTv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            mSendAgainBtn.setClickable(true);
            mSendAgainBtn.setBackground(getActivity().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.brown_btn_selector));
            mSendAgainBtn.setOnClickListener(onSendAgainButtonClick);
        }

    }.start();
}

    private String formatTime(long millis) {
    output = "";
    seconds = millis / 1000;
    long minutes = seconds / 60;

    seconds = seconds % 60;
    minutes = minutes % 60;

    String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
    String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);
    if (seconds < 10)
        secondsD = "0" + seconds;
    if (minutes < 10)
        minutesD = "0" + minutes;
    output =  minutesD+ " : " + secondsD;
    return output;
}
```

Comment: what you mean with "after a while"? Does it happen after a view starts of the timer (or app) or directly at the first start after some seconds?

Comment: i mean after some seconds of timer it is going wrong. for example when the timer starts it is ok but after seconds (10 seconds for example) it is going wrong

Comment: and you can exclude that it´s not because of multiple started timers or activities? Just for clarification...

Comment: i used Log.e("onTick",t); and saw that there is only on counter active at a time. log shows right numbers but UI timer not

Answer (score 0):

Might be you are writing this code in fragments or viewPager. countDown Timer is getting called multiple times. Try to put timer.start() in onClickListner of any button and check. Its perfectly working.

Comment: i used Log.e("onTick",t); and saw that there is only on counter active at a time. log shows right numbers but UI timer not

Comment: Add a button to your xml layout and write a listener for button and in on click of button start the timer. don't start timer directly in On Create method, So that we can conclude and say that only one timer is running.  Try it once and comment

Comment: i tried and same problem! note that i use Genymotion virtual .